# How does hibernate know which subclass to create when using Joined inheritence

Tags: hibernate, inheritance

if I have

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
Organization{
}

Account extends Organization{
   private Organization organization
}

Client extends Organization{
   private Organization organization
}

User {
   private Organization organization
}
```

When I call userDAO.get(1) and get back an instance of User, how does hibernate know to give me back an instance of Account rather than Client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Without discriminator

Hibernate performs an `OUTER JOIN` with every child table:

```
SELECT *,
case
    when a.id is not null then 0
    when c.id is not null then 1
    when u.id is not null then 2
end as clazz
FROM Organization o
    OUTER JOIN Account a
    OUTER JOIN Client c
    OUTER JOIN User u
```

And determines the actual type by looking at which `OUTER JOIN` actually returned something. Obviously there will be exactly one table from `Account`, `Client` and `User` holding a record that has the same `id` - and this denotes the actual type. This is what the awkward `case`/`when` does.

### With discriminator

If the discriminator column is present, `OUTER JOIN`s are still needed, but it is easier to determine the actual type, as it is explicitly stored in the database. No `case`/`when` magic.

### Summary

As you can see this inheritance strategy is very inefficient. It is much better when you explicitly ask for a given subtype, because Hibernate will do an `JOIN` with only a single table.

### See also:

- [Joined Inheritance](http://www.laliluna.de/jpa-hibernate-guide/ch09s04.html)
- [Joined Inheritance with Discriminator](http://www.laliluna.de/jpa-hibernate-guide/ch09s04.html)

Answer (score 1):

For each record hibernate can store an additional (discriminator) column in the main table that indicates which type is used.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: Applies to `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy only**, see @Tomazs' response for `JOINED` strategy.

Hibernate stores the explicit subclass used as some form of enumeration, generally as a string value, in the database. You can set the name of this column using the `@DescriminatorColumn` annotation, and then use the `@DiscriminatorValue` annotation on subclasses. When Hibernate goes to store an `Account` in the database, any rows which are specific to say, `Client`, are still stored for that `Account` but are set to `null`, and the `DiscriminatorColumn` is set to `"Account"`. Then, when the organization is deserialized, Hibernate looks at that `DiscriminatorColumn`, sees that the `Organization` is an `Account`, and gives you back that type of object.

The `DescriminatorColumn` can be changed to use other types of data, eg. not strings, using the `columnDefinition` parameter. By default the name of this column is `DTYPE`, and values for classes which do not have a `DiscriminatorValue` are the name of the class.

Comment: According to https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/ANN-140 hb does not use the descriminator with annotations